# Why does InsertedRows in system.events decrease?

Tags: clickhouse

We are monitoring the InsertedRows in system.events. We find this value decreases sometimes. During the testing, we do not restart the server. How and why does it happen? Thanks.

Comment: only one place in source code contains increment of InsertedRows
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/DataStreams/CountingBlockOutputStream.cpp#L22

did you monitor `SELECT * FROM system.asynchronous_metrics WHERE metric='Uptime'; ` ?


if you look when value InsetedRows was decreased
InsertedBytes should decreased too

which system you use for collecting metrics?
maybe you have some aggregation / preprocessing raw metric value in your monitoring system?

Comment: just add ref to your issue in github: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/9816

Comment: @Slach Thanks for the tips. Yes, as you said the monitory tool re-calculates the metric by dividing uptime....